# How to populate a QTextEdit, that is inside a QTabWidget, by opening a text file? [pyqt5, python]

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtextedit, qtabwidget

I am trying to use the  `self.textedit = qtw.QTextEdit()` widget that I declared from my MainWindow into my TextFileOpenedInNewTab class by doing this `self.main_window = MainWindow()` and using it like this `self.main_window.textedit.setPlainText(content)`. It works, but it has a bug. It opens a new window. which I do not intend to happen.

How do I properly use or call a widget I declared from another class in PyQt?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg

import resources 
# how to import resources: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdOoZ7edqXc&list=PLXlKT56RD3kBu2Wk6ajCTyBMkPIGx7O37&index=4


class TextFileOpenedInNewTab(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, content):
        super().__init__()

        # get the textedit from the MainWindow
        self.main_window = MainWindow()
         # text edit
        self.main_window.textedit.setPlainText(content)
        # making tabs as central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_window.textedit)

class BlankTab(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.textedit = qtw.QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textedit)


class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # text edit
        self.textedit = qtw.QTextEdit()
        
        # status bar
        self.statusbar = self.statusBar()
        self.statusbar.showMessage('Ready')
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Tab Widget Application")
        self.setWindowIcon(qtg.QIcon("./_icons/notepad.png"))
        
        """     Tabs        """ 
        # creating a tab widget
        self.tabs = qtw.QTabWidget()
        # making tabs closeable
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
        # this code allow the use of creating new tabs  
        self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True)
        # adding action when double clicked
        self.tabs.tabBarDoubleClicked.connect(self.tab_open_doubleclick)
        # adding action when tab close is requested
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.close_current_tab)
        # making tabs as central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
        # creating first tab
        self.add_new_tab("Untitled.txt")

        """     Menubar QMenus       """
        self.menuBar_open()
        self.menuBar_exit_file()

        self.initUI()
        self.show()
        
    def initUI(self):

        """     UI Functionalities       """
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        file_menu = menubar.addMenu('File')
        file_menu.addAction(self.open_file)
        file_menu.addSeparator()
        file_menu.addAction(self.exit_program) 

    def menuBar_open(self):
        self.open_file = qtw.QAction(qtg.QIcon(':/images/folder.png'),"Open...", self)
        self.open_file.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        self.open_file.setStatusTip('Open a file')
        self.open_file.triggered.connect(self.openFile)

    def menuBar_exit_file(self):
        self.exit_program = qtw.QAction(qtg.QIcon(':/images/close.png'), "Exit", self)
        self.exit_program.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exit_program.setStatusTip('Exit Program')
        self.exit_program.triggered.connect(self.close)


    # method for adding new tab
    def add_new_tab(self, label ="Untitled.txt"):

        # setting tab index
        index = self.tabs.addTab(BlankTab(), label)
        self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(index)


    # when double clicked is pressed on tabs
    def tab_open_doubleclick(self, index):
        
        # checking index i.e
        # No tab under the click
        if index == -1:
            # creating a new tab
            self.add_new_tab()


    # when tab is closed
    def close_current_tab(self, index):

        # if there is only one tab
        if self.tabs.count() < 2:
            # do nothing
            return
        # else remove the tab
        self.tabs.removeTab(index)


    def openFile(self):
        options = qtw.QFileDialog.Options()
        filenames, _ = qtw.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(
            self, 'Open a file', '',
            'All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py);;Text Files (*.txt)',
            options=options
        )
        if filenames:
            for filename in filenames:
                with open(filename, 'r') as file_o:
                    content = file_o.read()
                    self.tabs.addTab(TextFileOpenedInNewTab(str(content)), str(filename))


    def closeTab(self, index):
        tab = self.tabs.widget(index)
        tab.deleteLater()
        self.tabs.removeTab(index)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qtw.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:            
        # in every pyqt application it is required to create the object of QApplication
        app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        print('QApplication instance already exists: %s' % str(app))
        
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except SystemExit:
        print("Closing Window...")
```

Comment: That said, why are you creating a new instance of `MainWindow`? Also, that `self.textedit` is never used, so, trying to access its content it's completely pointless. Your code is very confusing. It should also be noted that there's really no point in adding a QMainWindow as a tab (which could also create some unexpected behavior), and you should just add a plain QWidget instead.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't aware of the implications of my formatting. It is a bad habit of mine to not follow social norms. That being said, I fixed what I wrote. Regarding the codes being confusing, this is a conglomeration of other people codes and mine that I put together.  Since I can't understand the Qt C++ documentation.

Comment: I used the QMainWindow because I prefer how the `QTextEdit` look like when `setCentralWidget` is used on it, as opposed to just normal layouts available for `QWidget`. This is more like a Rich Text Editor that will have tabs functionality. The `self.textedit` will be used later on. The text editor is already made: [link](https://github.com/rising-dancho/_notepad-pyqt5-python-) However, I cannot find a way to merge the tabs functionality with my Rich Text Editor.

Comment: @adfinem_rising the C++ documentation is fundamentally the same as the python one (the signature syntax may be a bit obscure at first, and some arguments could *rarely* be different, but the concept are always absolutely the same). Using QMainWindow or QWidget changes **absolutely nothing** on the look of the editor (especially considering that QMainWindow, as *any* other widget, inherits from QWidget). You could've seen slight differences in margins (which can be easily fixed with `setContentsMargins()`) but nothing else should change (and if it did, then you probably did something else). ->

Comment: @adfinem_rising The point remains, QMainWindow is intended as a top level widget, using it as a child for tabs or other widgets (with 2 specific exceptions, which are MDI areas a graphics views) is *not* its purpose and is always prone to unexpected behavior, so you should not use it for the wrong reason. Finally, if you're possibly going to open *more* than one new tab, you cannot obviously just have a single `self.textedit` instance shared between other objects. It seems that you have some confusion about classes and instances, so I strongly urge you to do more research on the topic.

Comment: @musicamante thank you for making things more clear. currently reading more about the topic. since i do have problems understanding how classes work in pyqt. i just started reading this ebook 'Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt' right now. any suggestions for where to start is welcome. thanks again!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are creating a new `QMainWindow` every time you open a new tab.

Both your `BlankTab` class and `TextFileOpenedInNewTab` class are subclassing `QMainWindow` so every time their constructors are called it is creating a separate window for each of them.  Both classes are unnecessary for what you are trying to achieve.

When creating a new tab the only widget constructor that needs to be called is the `QTextEdit`.

Try it like this:  I made some additional notes in the code where I made changes

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg

class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.textedit = qtw.QTextEdit()
        self.statusbar = self.statusBar()
        self.statusbar.showMessage('Ready')
        self.setWindowTitle("Tab Widget Application")
        self.setWindowIcon(qtg.QIcon("./_icons/notepad.png"))
        self.tabs = qtw.QTabWidget(self)
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.tabs.tabBarDoubleClicked.connect(self.tab_open_doubleclick)
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.close_current_tab)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
        self.add_new_tab("Untitled.txt")
        self.menuBar_open()
        self.menuBar_exit_file()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        file_menu = menubar.addMenu('File')
        file_menu.addAction(self.open_file)
        file_menu.addSeparator()
        file_menu.addAction(self.exit_program)

    def menuBar_open(self):
        self.open_file = qtw.QAction(qtg.QIcon(':/images/folder.png'),"Open...", self)
        self.open_file.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        self.open_file.setStatusTip('Open a file')
        self.open_file.triggered.connect(self.openFile)

    def menuBar_exit_file(self):
        self.exit_program = qtw.QAction(qtg.QIcon(':/images/close.png'), "Exit", self)
        self.exit_program.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exit_program.setStatusTip('Exit Program')
        self.exit_program.triggered.connect(self.close)

    def add_new_tab(self, label ="Untitled.txt"):
        index = self.tabs.addTab(qtw.QTextEdit(), label)  # create a new blank text edit widget
        self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(index)

    def tab_open_doubleclick(self, index):
        if index == -1:
            self.add_new_tab()\

    def close_current_tab(self, index):
        if self.tabs.count() < 2:
            return
        self.tabs.removeTab(index)


    def openFile(self):
        options = qtw.QFileDialog.Options()
        filenames, _ = qtw.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(
            self, 'Open a file', '',
            'All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py);;Text Files (*.txt)',
            options=options
        )
        if filenames:
            for filename in filenames:
                with open(filename, 'r') as file_o:
                    content = file_o.read()
                    editor = qtw.QTextEdit()   # construct new text edit widget
                    self.tabs.addTab(editor, str(filename))   # use that widget as the new tab
                    editor.setPlainText(content)  # set the contents of the file as the text


    def closeTab(self, index):
        tab = self.tabs.widget(index)
        tab.deleteLater()
        self.tabs.removeTab(index)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I merged the solution above with the following functionalities:

- new tab
- close tab
- save file

(since these things are implicitly needed for what the question is trying to achieve)

- open tab

(modified the `openFile` method to match with the new changes. thanks to the insightful comments by the man, the myth, the legend himself, [Alexander][1]

the improvements start with these lines of codes:

```
    import sys
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
    from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
    from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
    
    class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
    
            self.current_editor = self.create_editor()  # declares a variable for the create_editor method
            self.text_editors = [] # an array that stores the indexes of newly created QTextEdit object
    
            """ removed codes that are not part of the explanation"""

            self.tabs.tabBarDoubleClicked.connect(self.tab_open_doubleclick)
            self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.remove_editor)
            self.tabs.currentChanged.connect(self.change_text_editor) # whenever a different tab is clicked the change_text_editor method is called
            self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
```

this method creates and returns a new `QTextEdit` widget (or object)

```
    def create_editor(self):
        textedit = qtw.QTextEdit()
        return textedit
```

this method returns the index of the of the currently selected tab's `QTextEdit` stored in the `self.text_editors` array

```
  def change_text_editor(self, index):
        if index < len(self.text_editors):
            self.current_editor = self.text_editors[index]
```

now, since we are able to keep tabs on exactly which `QTextEdit` is currently selected at a given time. we would now be capable to do whatever we want with it by just calling `self.current_editor`, as if it was just some normal `QTextEdit` without the tab functionality.

here is the full runnable code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg

class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.current_editor = self.create_editor()  # declares a variable for the create_editor method
        self.text_editors = [] # an array that stores the indexes of newly created tabs

        self.statusbar = self.statusBar()
        self.statusbar.showMessage('Ready')
        self.setWindowTitle("Notepad with tabs")
        self.setWindowIcon(qtg.QIcon("./_icons/notepad.png"))
        self.tabs = qtw.QTabWidget(self)
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.tabs.tabBarDoubleClicked.connect(self.tab_open_doubleclick)
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.remove_editor)
        self.tabs.currentChanged.connect(self.change_text_editor) # whenever a different tab is clicked the change_text_editor method is called
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
        
        self.newFile()
        
        self.menuBar_new()
        self.menuBar_open()
        self.menuBar_close()
        self.menuBar_save()
        self.menuBar_exit_program()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        file_menu = menubar.addMenu('File')
        file_menu.addAction(self.new_file)
        file_menu.addAction(self.open_file)
        file_menu.addAction(self.save_file)
        file_menu.addSeparator()
        file_menu.addAction(self.exit_program)

    def create_editor(self):
        textedit = qtw.QTextEdit()
        return textedit

    def change_text_editor(self, index):
        if index < len(self.text_editors):
            self.current_editor = self.text_editors[index]

    def menuBar_new(self):
        self.new_file = qtw.QAction(qtg.QIcon(':/images/folder.png'),"New", self)
        self.new_file.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
        self.new_file.setStatusTip('New file')
        self.new_file.triggered.connect(self.newFile)

    def menuBar_open(self):
        self.open_file = qtw.QAction(qtg.QIcon(':/images/folder.png'),"Open", self)
        self.open_file.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        self.open_file.setStatusTip('Open a file')
        self.open_file.triggered.connect(self.openFile)
    
    def menuBar_save(self):
        self.save_file = qtw.QAction(qtg.QIcon(':/images/folder.png'),"Save", self)
        self.save_file.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')
        self.save_file.setStatusTip('Save a file')
        self.save_file.triggered.connect(self.saveFile)

    def menuBar_close(self):
        close_tab = qtw.QShortcut(qtg.QKeySequence("Ctrl+W"), self)
        close_tab.activated.connect(lambda:self.remove_editor(self.tabs.currentIndex()))

    def menuBar_exit_program(self):
        self.exit_program = qtw.QAction(qtg.QIcon(':/images/close.png'), "Exit", self)
        self.exit_program.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exit_program.setStatusTip('Exit Program')
        self.exit_program.triggered.connect(self.close)


    def remove_editor(self, index):
        if self.tabs.count() < 2:
            return
        self.tabs.removeTab(index)
        if index < len(self.text_editors):
            del self.text_editors[index]

    def create_editor(self):
        text_editor = qtw.QTextEdit()
        return text_editor

    def change_text_editor(self, index):
        if index < len(self.text_editors):
            self.current_editor = self.text_editors[index]

    # Input Functions
    def newFile(self, checked = False, title = "Untitled.txt"):
        self.current_editor = self.create_editor()
        self.text_editors.append(self.current_editor)
        self.tabs.addTab(self.current_editor, title)
        self.tabs.setCurrentWidget(self.current_editor)

    def tab_open_doubleclick(self, index):
        if index == -1:
            self.newFile()

    def openFile(self):
        options = qtw.QFileDialog.Options()
        filenames, _ = qtw.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(
            self, "Open a file", "",
            "All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py);;Text Files (*.txt)",
            options=options
        )
        if filenames:
            for filename in filenames:
                with open(filename, "r") as file_o:
                    content = file_o.read()
                    self.current_editor = self.create_editor() # similar to what the newFile method is doing
                    # editor = qtw.QTextEdit()  # construct new text edit widget
                    currentIndex = self.tabs.addTab(self.current_editor, str(filename))   # use that widget as the new tab
                    self.current_editor.setPlainText(content)  # set the contents of the file as the text
                    self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(currentIndex) # make current opened tab be on focus
    
        
    
    def saveFile(self):
        text = self.current_editor.toPlainText()
        filename, _ = qtw.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save file', None, 'Text files(*.txt)')
        if filename:
            with open(filename, "w") as handle:
                handle.write(text)
                print(self.tabs.currentIndex())
                print(str(filename))
                self.tabs.setTabText(self.tabs.currentIndex(), str(filename)) # renames the current tab with the filename
                self.statusBar().showMessage(f"Saved to {filename}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.resize(650,500)
    main.setMinimumSize(550,450)
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```